# Is it OK if I ask about GPU architecture?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I was wondering, there are some parts in a GPU which are unknown to me such as LD/ST and SFU and I wanted to ask somewhere. Is it ok if I ask it on Stack Overflow? Or should I bring it to somewhere else?

Comment: If you're asking about the actual chip design, you should also consider [electronics.se]

Comment: nice, I think this is what I'm looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific question about it, you can ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com). But if you are only asking for tips or links or a discussion - that would be off-topic.

Comment: I can't seem to find any reference for LD/ST for example, a google search brings me dozens of crap!

Comment: But I got the answer anyway, thank you.

Comment: Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much. So a question like: *What is LD/ST/SFU* would be to broud.

Comment: Well I want to give a presentation and I guess I'm overreacting, but I'm trying to know every little aspect of the GPU design in case someone asks :D

Comment: I see your point. I'll try [EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) and specify a certain GPU chip, but I wish NVIDIA had more documentation on these things.